# sharepoint 2010 FieldRenderingControl edit mode empty values

Tags: web-part, field-controls

I have a list and it has a content type called employee, i would like to render a particular column from the list and its values in a webpart. The column is a multivalue checkbox. It has some values selected.

When I try to render this control, its rendered without the actual values check, all the checkbox are defaulted/ unchecked.

Here is the code that I am using.

```
var ctrl = GetSharePointControls(Constants.FieldNewStarters, itemId, SPControlMode.Edit);
        this.pnlNew.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

the called method:

```
public static Control GetSharePointControls(string fieldname, int itemId, SPControlMode mode){
        BaseFieldControl webControl = null;
        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
            {
                using (var site = new SPSite("http://kw3l1d65:45678/"))
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList list = web.Lists["test1"];
                    SPField field = list.Fields.GetField(fieldname);

                    // check if the field is a buildIn field
                    // or can be rendered by a SharePoint Control
                    if (field != null && field.FieldRenderingControl != null && !field.Hidden)
                    {
                        SPField newField = list.Fields[field.Id];

                        webControl = newField.FieldRenderingControl;
                        webControl.ListId = list.ID;
                        webControl.ItemId = itemId;
                        webControl.FieldName = newField.Title;

                        if (itemId != 0)
                        {
                            var controlContext = SPContext.GetContext(HttpContext.Current,
                             list.DefaultView.ID, list.ID, list.ParentWeb);

                            //SPContext.Current.FormContext.SetFormMode(mode, true);
                            //controlContext.FormContext.SetFormMode(mode, true);
                            webControl.ItemContext = controlContext;
                            webControl.RenderContext = controlContext;
                        }

                        if (mode == SPControlMode.Display)
                        {
                            webControl.ID = Guid.NewGuid() + PrepareId(newField.Title);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            webControl.ID = PrepareId(newField.Title);
                        }

                        webControl.ControlMode = mode;
                    }
                }
            });
            return webControl;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LoggingService.LogError(LogCategories.General, ex.StackTrace);

            var errorLabel = new Label()
            {
                ID = "ErrorLabel",
                Text = string.Format("Error in GetSharePointControls:<br/>{0}", ex)
            };
            return errorLabel;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You mentioned issues with RunWithElevatedPrivileges. Where is the code executed and what is "http://kw3l1d65:45678"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `SPContext.Current.FormContext.FieldControlCollection.Add(webControl);`

Comment: looks like SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate is the issue. if i remove this , it works fine.